# Zooming on 1 Axis

Tags: 3d-view

I have a question about zooming the view on the X axis only. I created a 2D looking plot in 3D space and want to zoom in on one axis to see more details (to later export that as a movie, so it seems that Changing the Aspect Ratio of the output file wouldn't work). I have tried changing the focal length of the camera, but that affects both axes equally. I have also tried scaling and panning the view, but that does not give me the desired effect either. Is there a way to zoom only one axis in Blender? If so, how can I do it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To zoom only on the X axis you have to use an orthographic camera and look at the object from the right side. Then changing the _Orthographic Scale_ in the camera properties zooms in and out. But of course it zooms in on the Z as well. An image is 2-dimensional, zooming in on one axis zooms in on a second axis as well - or do you want your object to be scaled unevenly, like flattened so it stays the same height while the width becomes larger?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and, yes!, I want my objects to be scaled unevenly, to keep the same height while their width becomes larger, exactly that. Can it be done? (I did tried before with the Orthographic Scale and could not do it)

Comment: The more I think about it, the easiest way would be to not zoom at all. If you want to zoom to an object on the X axis but the height should stay the same, you can simply scale it on the Y axis. That makes it wider, but not taller. For multiple objects, parent them all to an empty and scale that on the Y axis. The important thing is to have the pivot point for scaling at the same Z height as the camera, and even better directly at the center of the camera's view. This would work similar with a perspective camera, but to make sure there is no perspective distortion use an orthographic camera.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help sir. I will do what I wanted the way you say. It works. Coming from math software I got too used to just zoom on the X and/or Y axis, but your approach does what I wanted.